# clickonce application message about harming computer

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have deployed test app to my **localhost**. 
Every time i try to install the app, the message appears: "this type of file could harm your computer"
Is there any way to get rid of this message? Because when user reads it, he might think he is downloading some virus :)

Thank you

Comment: If you could remove it, don't you think people distributing real trojans would also remove it? How does the user's computer know that your program isn't harmful?

Comment: Yep I guess you right. Thanks for an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to do this like Woobie said.